# OSX Catalina GCC/PIP Issue

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, pip, macos-catalina

I'm trying to install a tool through pip3 onto my Mac but I get the following error:

> compilation terminated.
>       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1**

I've noticed that others have this issue since Mohave and suggest changing the location to where the headers point to, however with the Catalina update the location changed to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include`, and after trying the `CPATH=` and `C_INCLUDE_PATH=` methods I am still stuck. Has anyone come across this issue also?

Full Error:

```
  **ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/v4/cl9rby0j17gct94qgsksmw9w0000gn/T/pip-install-5ud0hb2z/cchardet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/v4/cl9rby0j17gct94qgsksmw9w0000gn/T/pip-install-5ud0hb2z/cchardet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/v4/cl9rby0j17gct94qgsksmw9w0000gn/T/pip-record-x2sb36vg/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/v4/cl9rby0j17gct94qgsksmw9w0000gn/T/pip-install-5ud0hb2z/cchardet/
    Complete output (24 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/cchardet
    copying src/cchardet/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/cchardet
    copying src/cchardet/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/cchardet
    running build_ext
    building 'cchardet._cchardet' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/cchardet
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/ext
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/ext/uchardet
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/ext/uchardet/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/ext/uchardet/src/LangModels
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Isrc/ext/uchardet/src -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/cchardet/_cchardet.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/cchardet/_cchardet.o
    In file included from src/cchardet/_cchardet.cpp:609:0:
    /usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
     #include_next <stdlib.h>
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/v4/cl9rby0j17gct94qgsksmw9w0000gn/T/pip-install-5ud0hb2z/cchardet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/v4/cl9rby0j17gct94qgsksmw9w0000gn/T/pip-install-5ud0hb2z/cchardet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/v4/cl9rby0j17gct94qgsksmw9w0000gn/T/pip-record-x2sb36vg/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.**
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to reinstall your Xcode Command Line Tools after upgrading to Catalina:

`xcode-select --install`

Run the above command in a terminal and follow the prompts.